# c# sorting a textfile

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have a question about how to sort a text file.
I have a `srec` file and I need to sort it before I send it over `COM1`.
So during opening or before sending I need to sort the file.

Here's a example of my `srec` file:

> S2140338BE0E0606510004008D15FE915115FE9191CC
>   S2140338CE04008D15FE9006010242C78C0AB79C04AF
>   S2140338DE008D15FE91D6C78C0AB79C04088D1D0065
>   S2130338EE1A16270704088D1D001A0CC78C11190C
>   S20C038E880000000000000D23AA
>   S2100202C000033403000336C3000338DBDF
>   S2140347C0045C3F0510060504008D15FEFC1304006B
>   S2140347D08D15FEFD060104008D15FE80068304007C
>   S2140347E08D15FE821304008D15FE8806FF04008DCA
>   S2140347F015FE8906FF04008D15FE8E060104008D46

This is the source code:

```
StringList list = new StringList().FromFile(appfile.FileName);

        // Read file and put it in a list
        foreach (String line in list)
        {

            serialPort1.Write(line);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Bootfile and Applicationfile are send succesfully.");
```

Comment: `list.Sort()` is possibly the simplest way to go.

Comment: Sort it based on what?

Comment: Have you tried reading all the lines into an array of strings, sorting the array, and then writing the lines back into the file?

Comment: Stringlist is a variable from another .dll file i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you could complicate it, if the file is of reasonable size (e.g. it's not a **massive** file) so it can be easily held in memory, it should be as simple as this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("{PathToFile}");
lines.Sort();
File.WriteAllLines("{PathToFile}", lines);
```

where `{PathToFile}` is the fully qualified physical path to your file.

Here `ReadAllLines` returns a `string[]` and `WriteAllLines` writes back out a `string[]`.

Further, as proposed by Jim Mischel, another option would be something like this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename, File.ReadLines(filename).OrderBy(s => s));
```

The primary benefit of this approach is that the code is more elegant.

Comment: And presuming that straight-up lexicographic sort is desired (no special rules).

Comment: @DonBoitnott, yes of course. But I see nothing in the OP's question or the comments that suggest otherwise.

Comment: Another possibility: `File.WriteAllLines(filename, File.ReadLines(filename).OrderBy(s => s));`

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks friend, quite elegant! I suppose one other benefit to this is that it wouldn't actually read the entire file into memory would it because `ReadLines` is deferred. Is that correct?

Comment: trhe example is only a little piece of the file, The srec file itself exist out of 400 lines.

Comment: @00Koornstra, 400 lines is literally nothing. You could use either of the options proposed.

Comment: It would have to read the entire file into memory in order to sort it.

Comment: @JimMischel, so the `OrderBy` effectively ends up reading it all into memory?

Comment: Something like that. I'm not sure about the exact mechanism. But at some point the whole file has to be in memory so that it can be sorted. One nice thing about this approach, though, is that you could replace `.OrderBy` with `.OrderByLarge` or something like that, which would do a multi-pass merge sort or whatever, if necessary. Assuming, of course, that such an extension method actually existed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
List<string> list;
```

Read each line  until end of line and then add it  to the list.
Then sort the list.
Best way, after linq techniques, afaik.